# How are jsp pages executed,what's the principle in it?

Tags: jsp, execute

I'm reading the steps to build a web app skeleton:

http://maestric.com/doc/java/spring/setup#web_app_skeleton

And feel it's greatly different from other languages like PHP.

How is it executed?

Comment: I don't know how is /jsp/index.jsp executed,and how does the web.xml work

Comment: You're reading a spring tutorial. This is another framework "again". I hope that you realize that spring is unrelated to JSP and that you aren't trying to learn the whole bunch together at once, that would only lead to more confusion. As to an answer for your question, just google "jsp lifecycle".

Answer (score 2):

[web.xml](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/server_archive/articles/understanding_web_xml_files.html) is a deployment descriptor. It does not actually work in a way, the server (servlet container) reads this file to know what your application's needs are (what filters to create, servlets, configuration params etc).

Consider CGI for a second. In a CGI you have code that is executed and outputs HTML. The equivalent of this in Java is a [Servlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet). You have Java code that includes HTML.

The [JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Server_Pages) is a Servlet turned inside out. You have HTML that includes Java code. When "executing" a JSP, the server will in fact turn it inside out and transform it into a Servlet.

The servlet is then executed, not the JSP.

P.S. this is off course a simplistic description, a lot more is going on behind the scenes.